# THREE.js Skybox not working

Tags: three.js, webgl

i am trying to do my own version of a planetarium based on the book Up and running and i am getting a problem when trying to make a skybox.

I am using Chrome and the javascript console bring up an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in the line where the material is defined.

Am i missing some library? Or is it some change in three.js? I am using r55. The code is the following:

Thank you!

```
var urlPrefix   = "images/skybox/";
var urls = [ 
urlPrefix + "skyboxmid.jpg", urlPrefix + "skyboxback.jpg",
urlPrefix + "skyboxleft.jpg", urlPrefix + "skyboxfront.jpg",
urlPrefix + "skyboxright.jpg", urlPrefix + "skyboxtop.jpg" ];

var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
var shader  = THREE.ShaderLib['normalmap'];
shader.uniforms["tNormal"].texture = textureCube;
var material = new THREE.MeshShaderMaterial({
    fragmentShader  : shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader    : shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms    : shader.uniforms
});

skybox  = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100000, 100000, 100000, 1, 1, 1, null, true ), material );
scene.addObject( skybox );
```

Answer (score 10):

It is now

```
new THREE.ShaderMaterial()
```

and

```
shader.uniforms["tNormal"].value = textureCube;
```

The *Up and Running* book you are using is out of date.

Search the three.js examples directory instead. There are other ways of creating skyboxes.

three.js r.55